# How to know if torghost is safe to use?

Tags: ubuntu, ip, proxy

I found a [blog post](http://www.khromozome.com/torghost-channel-all-traffic-through-tor-network-in-kali-linux/) about torghost, I am wondering if this has some potential harmful software or have some potential risk in using it.

Comment: This could be better asked on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Commonly

A soft will do what for it's designed to.

Maybe more, maybe less! But for ensuring this, you have to read ***sources***.

So if sources are readable, this is already a good thing: You just have to read them! ... Ideally, once readed and validated, you have to compile the soft yourself, with a **trusted** compiler, before using the soft.

But if sources are closed, you just can't make your own opinion. You have to trust third party.

### About TorGhost

Source are available at https://github.com/susmithHCK/torghost, the main part is a python script, less than 180 lines length.

This seem easy to validate (even if this post don't).

Comment: Why downvote this?

Comment: I didn't downvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of TorGhost. It's 100% safe, and it doesn't contain any malicious code. Don't worry.

Here is the link to the tutorial: [TorGhost – channel all traffic through tor network in kali linux](http://www.khromozome.com/torghost-channel-all-traffic-through-tor-network-in-kali-linux/).

Comment: Why did you not tell that TorGhost is written in Python and is available as source, so could be easily *validated* by security expert.